# Write data to excel template

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I need to create some excel tables, but these tables don't have simple look.
There are some pictures, some special fonts etc.
But the complicated parts are static, that means always the same.

So my idea was, I will create an excel-template with these tricky parts and then from python just insert dynamic data to this template.

I am working with pandas framework, but I didn't find a way how to do that with or without this framework.

Any idea?

Comment: Please show us what code you've tried.

Comment: @jbarker2160: That's not really relevant here, and not a productive comment. There isn't any code he could have tried, given the tools that he's mentioned in the question and the tags. If you don't think this question is a good fit for Stack Overflow, then comment on why you believe that, and/or downvote the question.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way to do this with any of the usual "direct file manipulation" libraries in Python (xlrd, xlwt, XlsxWriter, OpenPyXL; these are what pandas uses).  The reason is that the structure of a workbook file is such that it's impossible or prohibitively difficult (depending on whether you're talking about .xls or .xlsx) to do anything resembling "in-place" editing, short of re-implementing Excel itself.

So for what you're trying to do, your best option is to let Excel do the work.  (I'm assuming you can run Excel, since you mention that you'd like to create Excel templates.)  There are ways to automate Excel, the most straightforward probably being Microsoft's VBA or VBScript.  But if you want to do it in Python, you can, using [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) or [pywinauto](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/).

Comment: _"in-place" editing"_ I don't know if it supports in-place editing, but this link shows OpenPyExcel supports [direct cell assignment](https://gist.github.com/tnhu/33a762d8c76aad25189114dffd9df6a8).